# Undo setfacl changes

Tags: windows, permissions, cygwin, acl

Using Cygwin in a virtual machine, I ran this command

```
setfacl --remove-all /cygdrive/c
```

After that I noticed this message:

```
C:\ is not accessible.
Access is denied.
```

I undid this change by restoring a snapshot. Then I ran this command

```
setfacl --remove-default /cygdrive/c
```

This did not deny access to the drive, but it did put a lock icon on any folders
created after that.

[image: remove default]

Assuming that I had run these commands outside of a virtual machine, could these
problems be fixed without reinstalling Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following commands will fix it. After setfacl trashes the
permissions, you need to temporarily take ownership of `C:\`, restore the
permissions then set the owner back. Of course this is contingent on either
having backed up the permissions beforehand, or perhaps transferring them from
a clean virtual machine.

```sh
cd /cygdrive/c
icacls . /save acl.txt
setfacl --remove-all .
takeown /f .
icacls . /grant users:f
icacls acl.txt /grant users:f
icacls . /restore acl.txt
icacls . /setowner 'NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller'
```

Comment: I mistakenly did this last night to try to fix umask issues. The solution you provided isn't working for me. I get "Error: Current working irectory has restricted permissions which render it inaccessible as Win32 working directory. Can't start native Windows application from here." when I try to run the command "icacls . /save acl.txt". Any ideas?

Comment: I tried using my laptop to export the normal permissions for C:\, but I get "permission denied, Successfully processed 0 files; Failed processing 0 files" when I try to run the second command in your list.

Comment: in a windows command prompt, typing takeown /f C:\ allows you to use the windows permissions dialog to change the security settings.